# setInterval text javascript

Tags: javascript, php, settimeout, setinterval

i want to show the `text` and `image` immediately when i enter my webpage. Right now my image appear immediately but the text appear after 2 seconds when i open my webpage. Here my code:

```
<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}

var text = ["<?php
    $conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM product";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $code3 = $row["mtitle"];
        echo $code3.'","';
    }
?>"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");


function change() {
  elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
  counter++;
  if (counter >= text.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}
change(); setInterval(change, 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: Your current code calls `carousel()` immediately, but only calls `change()` indirectly via `setInterval()`. So why don't you use `setInterval()` for both?

Comment: i edit the question, i use setInterval for both but the text still delay for 2 seconds?

Comment: You realise your `text` array is going to have an empty last entry due to that trailing comma?

Comment: As to your question, that's how `setInterval` works. If you want something to happen right away and then every 2 seconds, use `change(); setInterval(change, 2000);`

Comment: @Phil , yes that is the problem. i cant delete that comma because if i do so, the text will not change every 2 seconds. because that text is from my database.

Comment: just add `change()` at the bottom.

Comment: @dandavis. where to add?

Answer (score 0):

After your recent update of the code in your question, things should already have improved.

But you should really merge the two intervals together, since you want to keep the two actions (image and text) happening at the same time, without the risk that they get out of sync.

Secondly, the way you define your `text` array is not best practice. Imagine how things would go wrong if one of your texts contains double quotes... Instead use JSON.

Finally, use variable names that better indicate what they are about. *x* suggests an x-coordinate, not a list of DOM Elements. Name it `slides` or something. Plurals for things that are arrays also give a clue: `text` is not one text in your code, but an array of texts, so call it `texts` in plural. All this helps to make your code more readable.

```
// Use JSON notation instead of fabricating the array with concatenations
var texts = <?php
    $conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM product";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

    while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data = $row["mtitle"]; // Push to an array
    }
    echo json_encode($data); // Encode the array as JSON text: ["abc", "def", ...]
?>;

var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");

(function carousel(slideIndex, textIndex) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
    // The variable changeText is automatically defined upon page load, so use it  
    changeText.textContent = texts[textIndex]; 
    // Change image and text every 2 seconds
    setTimeout(carousel.bind(null, (slideIndex + 1) % slides.length, 
                                   (textIndex + 1) % texts.length)), 2000);
})(0, 0); // Execute on page load, keeping the counters as local variables
```